# Sequelize error: Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property '_pseudo of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am cloned this app https://github.com/sequelize/express-example which appears to be the official sequelize express example but I get this error when I try to run it

`Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property '_pseudo' of undefined
 at conformInclude (/Users/wasswasam/express-example-master/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:277:14)`

I am not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure myself but I do encounter this problem before. And I managed to solve this by removing the include param for findAll function

```
models.User.findAll({
    include: [ models.Task ]
  })
```

to

```
models.User.findAll()
```

The only think I can think is that you does not have the model it need. 
Hope this help.

Answer (score 5):

I get this error when the object in the `include` array is undefined. Usually caused by a dependency loop or a misspelled import.